# Call Bundled SBT's Commands in IntelliJ Scala Plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to call `gen-android` command after installing `android-sdk-plugin` to the project. However, I can't find out how to call a command of the bundled SBT, or do it outside of IDE.

How do you call commands of a bundled SBT of Scala plugin (v.2.2.0) in IntelliJ (v.15.0.3)? Or, is it possible to use the SBT executable outside IntelliJ?

I can of course use a normal SBT regardless but am just curious if I can do everything using one different SBT inside IDE (because it'd be convenient!)

Comment: Do it outside of the ide, and yes, you can `java -jar sbt-launcher.jar` that is bundled with the scala plugin. It is located somewhere in your plugin install directory of intellij.

Comment: @pfn I couldn't find `sbt-launcher` in my whole computer.

Comment: I had the name wrong, `sbt-launch.jar`

Comment: @pfn that works, thank you :) btw does this store cache in different place when executed outside IDE?

Comment: Got it. Thank you a lot for your help @pfn